# App works on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an app that is using the open source PSStackedView to implement a twitter-like interface. The app is working great on simulator, but when I run it on the device, as soon as I try to add a view controller to the stack the app crashes and highlights `viewController.view.height = [self screenHeight];` that line as `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1`

The app then just hangs on the device. I have tried debugging with zombies enabled, but it shows nothing problematic.

I am sick over this because I just finally got things going on the device, I have poured so much time into this app! Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app isn't hanging - it's just hitting a breakpoint at that line, which most likely you set by accident. Go to the line where your code stops, and press Cmd + \ to disable the breakpoint. You can also press Ctrl+Cmd+Y to continue running the app past the breakpoint. There are other hotkeys and commands you can try under Xcode's Debug menu.

Comment: As a side note: you can also disable every breakpoint by clicking the little puffy arrow button on the top bar.

Comment: Thank you. The breakpoint I had was an "all exceptions" breakpoint. Disabling that gave me an error message specific enough that I was able to debug the issue from there. Much appreciated!

Comment: As a side note:  If you get caught on an exception breakpoint, usually hitting the "play" button twice will get you to the error message.